# typical UITableView unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

I'm having this "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error, I'm almost sure is some kind of memory management issue but right now I'm pretty much tired of having to find the bug. 
The TableView displays the cells well as long as you don't scroll down, if you do..
app crashes. 
The only property I use is called "places", I've already checked if I didn't miss a "self.".

so.. here's my code:

```
#import "PlacesViewController.h"
#import "FlickrFetcher.h"
#import "SinglePlaceViewController.h"

@implementation PlacesViewController

@synthesize places;

- (NSArray *)places
{
    if (!places) {
        NSSortDescriptor *content = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_content" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *unsortedPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];    
        places = [unsortedPlaces sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: content, nil]];
    }
    return places;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Top Places";
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.places.count;
}

- (NSDictionary *)placeAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self.places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PlacesTableViewCell";
    NSLog(@"%@", [FlickrFetcher topPlaces]);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *location = [[self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath] objectForKey:@"_content"];
    NSArray *splitLocation = [location componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
    cell.textLabel.text = [splitLocation objectAtIndex:0];
    if (splitLocation.count == 2)
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [splitLocation objectAtIndex:1];
    if (splitLocation.count == 3)
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[splitLocation objectAtIndex:1] stringByAppendingString:@","] stringByAppendingString:[splitLocation objectAtIndex:2]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    SinglePlaceViewController *spvc = [[SinglePlaceViewController alloc] init];
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    spvc.placeId = [[self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath] objectForKey:@"place_id"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:spvc animated:YES];
    [spvc release];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [places release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Thank You very much for your help and I'm really sorry for making you all guys do a bit of work for me.

Comment: Can you leave out the whole `// Configure the cell...` part and scroll? I know this won't show text, but does it crash? Please post the stacktrace and the complete console output.

Comment: What class did `PlacesViewController` inherit? You should review delegate of your tableview

Comment: Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint in your project? Where is the message getting sent? Who is the receiver?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much info about the error so i can only guess:

The error indicates that the object that get the message `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` don't actually have this method implemented.
But since you DID implemented it, the only reason i can think of is that you are messing with your tableView's "dataSource" property and changing it to something you shouldn't.

Make sure that the dataSource is your `PlacecViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like to me, the getter method for your `places` property is not retaining the value it returns.  You are setting it to an autoreleased instance of `NSArray` you're getting from the `sortedArray` method.  I'm willing to bet it's being released after it displays your initial tableview cells.